# I don't know how to display my own pages with Symfony using MAMP

Tags: php, macos, symfony, mamp

I'm currently learning symfony.

I would like to display a page I created with MAMP in a browser, but I can't get it to display even if I type in the URL I registered in routes.yaml.
I don't know what the problem is, so I'm having trouble.
Can you please help me?

---

What I have tried:

1. Create a controller

   ```
   php bin/console make:controller
   ```
2. edit route.yaml

   ```
   home_page:
       path: /home_page
       controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
   ```
3. do this command

   ```
   composer require symfony/apache-pack
   ```

---

Type "`localhost:8888/mysite/home_page`" into Google Chrome

Even after doing these, I still get

```
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

The directory created is located at MAMP/htdoc.

Type "`localhost:8888`" and "`localhost:8888/mysite`" into browser to view the index.html I have placed.

However, when I enter "`localhost:8888/mysite/home_page`", I cannot open the twig that I created with "`php bin/console make:controller`". I can't open twig.

I'm sorry for my bad English. Please help me.

Comment: With this command　"php bin/console debug:router" , the
The path has been confirmed. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with
localhost:8888/mysite/index.php/home_page